# Is there some flexible "flush floats" recommendation command (similar to \pagebreak[priority])?

Tags: floats

Two questions on one subject:

1. Is there a command (in the standard packages) to suggest flushing floats after that point with some "priority" value ranging from "suggest" to "force" (similar to \pagebreak[priority])?
2. Do the default LaTeX sectioning commands add such commands (so that floats tend less to accumulate across sections, subsections, etc.)?
   Only chapters seem to flush floats.

Comment: Using the afterpage package one can `\afterpage{\clearpage}` and not waste space.  However, there is usually a reason why floats back up.  First, they are printed in order, so one bad float will stop everything.  Second there are size restrictions for top and bottom floats (`\topfraction\columnheight` and `\bottomfraction\columnheight`}.  Either increase these limits or add [p].

Answer (score 0):

The default code in latex can only flush code at a page break and in the standard classes only `\chapter` executes a `\clearpage`.

It isn't clear how you see a priority working, you could add a `\pagebreak[2]` to (say) `\section` level headings and then, if the page break is taken, any pending floats would be considered.

Comment: I think the problem is that the float mechanism is purely based on the geometry of the float, and not on the "geometry" that describes the distance between definition of the float and actual output position. If that distance would be a kind of penalty, some floats might be output earlier I guess. That's why I thought there might be a mechanism to bias towards flushing the floats. One specific problem seems to be "[p]" floats mixed with non-[p] floats (that are added to the non-full page of pictures, delaying their output significantly).

Comment: @U.Windl all floats are output _as soon as possible_ subject to the constraints you have set, so it is hard to know how a priority system would work, the only thing you could do is give a possibility of being held back and floating further. But if you provided an example someone could debug the specific code path, in general there is not a lot you can say.