# Optional pagebreak with flushing floats

Tags: page-breaking, clearpage

I read this post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516863/is-there-some-flexible-flush-floats-recommendation-command-similar-to-pagebr) about page breaks with priority without being satisfied with it. I was wondering if there exists a way to have a `clearpage`-like command with request levels (like `pagebreak` has) ?

I'm trying to have consistent footnotes positioning while being able to specify where page breaks are encouraged (not forced).

Here is a sample code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

This is a test.\footnote{This is a footnote}

%\newpage % Bottom footnote, but mandatory page break
%\pagebreak[4] % Optional page break, but top footnotes
\clearpage % Botton footnote, but mandatory page break

More text.

\end{document}
```

A secondary question would be: if such a command exists, how can you customize how levels are considered in the page-breaking process?